# I want to display all the data in my console from the data base using ArrayList

Tags: java, database, jakarta-ee

Hello all i want is to display entire content of my database table on Console. I am trying to fetch record from database first and store in ArrayList but it does not display any  thing insted it display this:

```
[com.suven.java.EmployeeDTO@970c0e]
[com.suven.java.EmployeeDTO@970c0e, com.suven.java.EmployeeDTO@987197] 
[com.suven.java.EmployeeDTO@970c0e, com.suven.java.EmployeeDTO@987197, com.suven.java.EmployeeDTO@497904]
```

I am fully confused to what to do. My code is:

```
EmployeeDTO java file

public class EmployeeDTO 
{
    //private properties
    private int empNo;
    private String eName;
    private String jobTitle;
    //setters
    public void setEmpNo(int val){empNo=val;}
    public void setEName(String val){eName=val;}
    public void setJob(String val){jobTitle=val;}
    // getters
    public int getEmpNo(){return empNo;}
    public String getEName(){return eName;}
    public String getJob(){return jobTitle;}
}
```

My EmployeeList java code is:

```
public class EmployeeList 
{

  public static void main(String argv[]) 
  {
   Connection conn=null;
   Statement stmt=null;
   ResultSet rs=null;      

   try 
   {
    // Load the JDBC driver  
    // This can be skipped for Derby, but derbyclient.jar has to be in the CLASSPATH   
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    String accessFileName = "E:/Database/java";
    conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access  Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ="+accessFileName+".accdb;");

    // Build an SQL String 
    String sqlQuery = "SELECT * from Employee"; 

    // Create a Statement object
    stmt = conn.createStatement(); 

    // Execute SQL and get obtain the ResultSet object
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(sqlQuery);  
    ArrayList<EmployeeDTO> employees = new ArrayList<EmployeeDTO>();
    // Process the result set - print Employees
    while (rs.next())
    { 
        EmployeeDTO currentEmp = new EmployeeDTO();

        currentEmp.setEmpNo(rs.getInt("EMPNO"));
        currentEmp.setEName(rs.getString("ENAME"));
        currentEmp.setJob(rs.getString("JOB_TITLE"));
        employees.add(currentEmp);
        System.out.println(employees);
    }       
   } 
   catch( SQLException se ) 
   {
      System.out.println ("SQLError: " + se.getMessage ()+ " code: " + se.getErrorCode ());
   }
   catch( Exception e )
   {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
      e.printStackTrace(); 
   }
   finally
   {
       // clean up the system resources
       try
       {
       rs.close();     
       stmt.close(); 
       conn.close();  
       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } 
   }
}
}
```

My database is:

```
Employee
EMPN     ENAME     JOB_TITLE
1        abc       xyz
2        pqr       mno
3        lmn       hij
```

Please help me i have posted my full code and database
where am i going wrong how to display it in a console

Comment: You should take a look at the [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) page so you can improve the question yourself next time.

Answer (score 3):

You have to implement `toString()` in your `EmployeeDTO` class. If you are using Eclipse you can generate the method: right click the class -> Source -> Generate toString()...

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `toString` in your `EmployeeDTO` class. You could use `String.format` to do the formatting:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
   return String.format("%d\t%s\t%s", empNo, eName, jobTitle);
}
```

To print each `employee` on a separate line you could use:

```
for (EmployeeDTO employee : employees) {
    System.out.println(employee);
}
```

Comment: thanx it worked but the out put is in this format  [EmployeeDTO [empNo=1, eName=Suryakant Yadav, jobTitle=Android Developer], EmployeeDTO [empNo=2, eName=Archie Dsouza, jobTitle=Office Manager], EmployeeDTO [empNo=3, eName=Suyog Sawant, jobTitle=WT Developer]]  i want to display data in row by row like it is displayed in data base

Comment: if it is possible to print the data like in data base

Comment: Thanx again my last doubt cant i break all the data for a new line so that i can display single data on single line

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<EmployeeDTO> employees = new ArrayList<EmployeeDTO>();
// Process the result set - print Employees
while (rs.next())
{ 
    EmployeeDTO currentEmp = new EmployeeDTO();

    currentEmp.setEmpNo(rs.getInt("EMPNO"));
    currentEmp.setEName(rs.getString("ENAME"));
    currentEmp.setJob(rs.getString("JOB_TITLE"));
    employees.add(currentEmp);
    System.out.println(employees);
}
```

In this code, you are putting Object into ArrayList, not an actual String/Value into it. That's why you are getting  as com.suven.java.EmployeeDTO@970c0e

Comment: Your answer should also include the solution which is pretty simple and straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need an implementation of `toString()` in your DTO. You'd implement that such that it returns a string consisting of your employee name, job etc... Here's a link to [10 tips for implementing toString()](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/09/override-tostring-method-java-tips-example-code.html).

I note also that you print the *list* of employees after you read each employee. I suspect rather that you need to print the employee itself.

```
System.out.println(employees); // this is the list itself!
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it all right except in the line

```
System.out.println(employees);
```

in the while loop.

You cannot display ArrayList like that with out overloading toString() in your EmployeeDTO class.

Instead, to display array list, do this after the while loop

```
for(EmployeeDTO emp : employees)
{
    System.out.println(emp.getEmpNo() + " " +  emp.getEName() + " " + emp.getJob());
}
```

Comment: thanx it display the data as i want, but my i have one doubt ie even when i remove the tostring method from EmploeeDTO then also it displays the data why is it so please explain it to me if possible?

Comment: you are welcome!! In the above case there is no need to override toString() because we are accessing single object from the arraylist in the for loop every time and getting the values of members of that object using getter methods (getEmpNo(),  getEName(), emp.getJob()).